# Access variable in try block from finally block python

Tags: python, try-catch, python-decorators

With help of Github and stackoverflow, I have written log decorator for measuring the execution time of a function and raise exception if function doesn't execute. The code is:

```
def log(logger):
    def log_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                start_time = time.time()
                logger.info('Starting function -' + function.__name__)
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as err:
                logger.exception(err)
                raise
            finally:
                end_time = time.time()
                logger.info('End function - ' + function.__name__)
                logger.info('Execution time %s milliseconds', (end_time-start_time)*1000)
        return wrapper
    return log_decorator
```

I have few questions:

1. Local variable might be referenced before assignment warning while accessing **start_time** from finally block. How to resolve it?
2. The exception has empty raise. Is it good practice?

Comment: There's no need for `start_time` to be global; it's only used in the wrapper, so let it be a local variable. Whether or not to use `raise` or `raise err` is probably a matter of opinion. The third question is far too broad, and indicates there could be a question here for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's better to raise an exception with specific information so `raise err` is preferred over `raise`. But in this case you are catching a general `Exception` which is not recommended (and will not cause any difference using `raise err`).

Comment: @asn-0184 `raise` does exactly what `raise err` does; the fact that you gave a name to the caught exception isn't relevant. Catching `Exception` here is find if the intent is to simply logging it before re-raising it for someone else to handle. It's basically the same as not catching it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't make `start_time` global. If you want to access it outside of the wrapper, then declare it outside the wrapper.
2. It doesn't matter, although I personally prefer raising an error explicitly.
3. That depends on what you want to use it for.